# mod rewrite для админки

Tags: php

В корне сайта есть htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Как написать такой же, тока для админки?)
Папка admin

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает прописать директорию(папку)

Answer (score 1):

Поместите перед этим правилом другое, которое будет последним (ключ **[L]**):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?admin/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ admin/index.php?%1 [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: @vinnie Поправил ответ

Comment: не работает(((